# How best can I Clean up data sent back by Gemini in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, google-gemini

I am working on an AI blog project using Google Gemini as my base LLM model. However, while trying to test and run the code, and perhaps store it in a database an issue continues to persist:

```
Invalid line format: **1. Personal Finance**
Invalid line format: In the 
Invalid line format: Your budget is not set in stone. As your income and expenses change, you need to review and adjust your budget regularly. This will ensure that your budget remains effective and aligned with your financial goals.
Invalid line format: **Why Financial Literacy is Important**
Invalid line format: - Use online resources and tools.
Invalid line format: Passive income is income that you earn without actively working for it. It's the holy grail of personal finance, allowing you to generate wealth while you sleep, travel, or pursue your passions.
Invalid line format: **Types of Passive Income**
{
  id: '65e14e2',
  title: 'Finance',
  slug: 'finance',
  image: '/financeimage.png'
}
{
  title: '** The Ultimate Guide to Budgeting for Beginners: A Step-by-Step Plan to Financial Freedom',
  author: null,
  featureImage: null,
  content: null
}
```

I should mention that prompting Gemini returned the data in this format (with an asterix '*'):

```
 **Category: Finance**

**1. Investing**

**a. Title:** The Art of Value Investing: A Beginner's Guide to Finding Undervalued Stocks
**Author:** Amelia Carter
**Feature Image:** A stock market chart with a green arrow pointing upward
**Content Image:** A photo of Warren Buffett, the renowned value investor
**Content:**
- Explains the basics of value investing, including how to identify undervalued stocks
- Provides tips for conducting thorough research and analyzing financial statements
- Shares real-life examples of successful value investments
- Includes a personal story about the author's first value

**c. Title:** The Psychology of Investing: Overcoming Emotional Biases
**Author:** Sophia Patel
**Feature Image:** A photo of a person making a financial decision
**Content Image:** A diagram illustrating common cognitive biases in investing
**Content:**
- Discusses the psychological factors that influence investment decisions
- Identifies common biases, such as overconfidence and loss aversion
- Provides techniques for managing emotions and making rational investment choices
- Shares a personal story about the author's struggles with emotional investing

**e. Title:** The Importance of Financial Literacy: Empowering Yourself with Knowledge
**Author:** Emily Chen
**Feature Image:** A photo of a person reading a book about finance
- Includes a personal story about the author's own financial education journey
```

I tried sanitizing the code, cleaning it up as best as I could to no avail. Here is a copy of the part of the code to that effect:

```
try { 
                const response = result.response;
                const text = response.text();

                const categories = [];
                let currentCategory = null;

                const lines = text.split('\n');

                for (const line of lines) {
                    if (line.startsWith('**Category:')) {
                        // Start of a new category
                        const categoryName = line.replace('**Category:', '').trim();
                        currentCategory = { title: categoryName, posts: [] };
                        categories.push(currentCategory);
                    } else if (line.startsWith('**') && line.includes(':')) {
                        // Start of a new post within the current category
                        const postInfo = line.replace('**', '').split(':');
                        const postField = postInfo[0].trim();
                        const postValue = postInfo.slice(1).join(':').trim(); // Handles ':' in content

                        if (postField === 'a. Title') {
                            currentCategory.posts.push({ title: postValue, author: null, featureImage: null, content: null });
                        } else {
                            // Update the last added post with additional information
                            const lastPost = currentCategory.posts[currentCategory.posts.length - 1];
                            if (postField === 'b. Author') {
                                lastPost.author = postValue;
                            } else if (postField === 'c. Feature Image') {
                                lastPost.featureImage = postValue;
                            } else if (postField === 'd. Content') {
                                lastPost.content = postValue;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (line.trim() !== '') {
                        console.error('Invalid line format:', line);
                    }
                }

                // Iterate over the extracted categories and posts
                for (const category of categories) {
                    try {
                        // Create or update the category in the database
                        const dbCategory = await prisma.category.upsert({
                            where: { slug: catSlug },
                            update: {},
                            create: {
                                title: postCat,
                                slug: catSlug,
                                image: tab.image,
                            },
                        });

                      
                        for (const post of category.posts) {
                            console.log(post);
                            await prisma.post.create({
                                data: {
                                    title: post.title,
                                    author: post.author,
                                    featureImage: post.featureImage,
                                    content: post.content,
                                    slug: catSlug,
                                    category: { connect: { id: dbCategory.id } },
                                },
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error processing category or post:', error);
                    }
                }
                console.log('Data stored successfully');

                // Respond with success message
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "Content generation was completed successfully" });

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error generating content:', error);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error generating content' });
}
```

this is done with a schema model with a logic that associates one post with a category in a one-to-many relationship where one category can have many posts:

```
model Post {
  id               String       @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title            String?
  views            Int          @default(0)
  createdAt        DateTime     @default(now())
  comments         Comments[]
  User             User?        @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  userEmail        String?
  author           String?
  categorySlug     String
  userId           String?      @db.ObjectId
  category         Category?    @relation(fields: [categorySlug], references: [slug])
  categoryId       String?      @db.ObjectId
  slug             String       @unique
}

model Category {
  id    String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title String?
  slug  String  @unique
  image String
  Posts Post[]
}
```

Can you give me pointers, suggest tools/packages or perhaps prompts examples I can use to extract the texts, and resolve this issue. I can't seem to be able to send it to a database without parsing it correctly. Thanks in advance.